# Pyinstaller not compiling jinga2 when using pandas style

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile python program using pyinstaller. My program uses pandas, in which I used pandas.styles which seems to use jinja2.

Now I have installed all the dependencies but then when I compile the program and run it, I end up getting this error.

I have done a lot of research and it seems to be a problem with pyinstaller not recognizing or not finding a template. I am a bit confused because when pandas is imported, shouldn't that also grab the jinja2 dependency?

As for solutions, I have tried using cxfreeze with no avail would greatly appreciate the help

The problem lines in this one line of code `rf.style.format` from my understanding `style` comes from jinja2 and I am not using a template as this program runs fine when I run the .py file but it when I using pyinstaller to create .exe file that's when this error happens.

````
  File "Billing.py", line 613, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 898, in style
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\anime\.virtualenvs\fbsdcode-yldzxpjz\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 135, in Styler
  File "lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
  File "lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
  File "lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
  File "lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 248, in get_source
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1404, in has_resource
  File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1474, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069303/notimplementederror-cant-perform-this-operation-for-unregistered-loader-type)

Comment: I am using `pandas.style.format` which from my understanding is that `pandas.style` uses jinja2. The program runs fine with its not compiled the issues comes in when I am trying to compile it into .exe using pyinstaller that is when i encounter the issue